# Using Public IP (assigned from ISP) in local network

Tags: networking, router, internet, ip, isp

I'm an ordinary home user, who have 3 PCs, and i'm connected to the internet through an ordinary modem/router.

I have received one public IP address from my ISP (in addition to another public wan one).

let's say it is **197.45.238.20** and its mask is **255.255.255.0**

I have installed a web server on one machine of the three i have, and i want that web server to be accessible from the internet.

and i want that machine also to be accessible to my two other PCs as a local network peer (in the range 192.168.1.x).

**note**: I had to disable the NAT in order to allow the web server to use its public IP not the router wan IP, but that prevents the two other PCs from reaching the internet (after changing their IPs to the web server range (**197.45.238.x**).

How can i do that?

Comment: Use port forwarding instead of disabling NAT, if at all. I'd rather put the webserver outside of your local net.

Answer (score 0):

Your ISP gave you 1 public IP so you will have to use that one in order to communicate with the rest of the world. So the address of your home network will be 197.45.238.20. Since you have a web server running on one of the 3 machines you want to forward port 80 on the modem/router in order for that machine to be publicly accessible on the address 197.45.238.20(:80).

Router WAN IP:197.45.238.20;
Assuming the web server machine has the following IP 192.168.1.100 you want to forward traffic on port 80 to 192.168.1.100;

Since the web server machine is on the local network it will already be accessible to the other machine on the network.

Also remember to give your web server a static IP within the LAN or the port forwarding will fail when the IP address of that machine changes.

I'm not sure what you mean by "in addition to another public wan one" though.

Comment: By "in addition to another public wan one" i mean that instead of the dynamically assigned IP address that i got every time i Connect or switch on the router, i have got a fixed one. that one i have no control over it, but of course i can use that IP to forward to specific ports.

Comment: I assumed something on those lines as well. Thank you for clarifying. I assume you'd like your web server to have that particular address(197.45.238.20) but I don't think it is possible to do so unless you configure your web server to act as a router/modem which in my opinion will be too much work for very little advantages. For a web server, forwarding ports 80 and 443(if using SSL) on the router/modem should suffice.